# SEC Edgar - Can someone help me identify what this text represents?

Tags: text, edgar

https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1383094/000119312518268345/0001193125-18-268345.txt

The part I'm unsure how to read can be found by using ctrl+f on the following characters: M_]C_X0QQ17AI9@

This is the start of a section I am not familiar with, which contains a long block of text characters with each row starting with "M".

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The character sequence you see there is an encoded JPEG picture. You can recognize this by checking the starting character sequence - that is:

```
begin 644 g61300267.jpg
```